# jqgrid + jQuery UI Multiselect

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am trying to show a multiselect list in editGridRow (not inline editing).
As I've read in other answers I've tried using:

```
dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { $(el).multiselect(); }, 50); }
```

but I had no luck.

Any suggestions?